# Codenameone, How can i call or load android native progress dialog?

Tags: java, android, codenameone

How can i use the android native progress dialog instead of the default cn1 one when i do network requests.

I have tried using native Interfaces i cant quite get them right

I know this is possible because i saw when i use the `BrowserComponent` it uses the progress dialog preloader

I want to replace the below `InfiniteProgress` with android one.

```
        InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
        Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
        r.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
```

[image: android progress dialog]

Answer (score 0):

`BrowserComponent` is implemented natively so you will have to use native interfaces if you want to do that although there is no reason I can think of for you to do that.

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: Thanks Shai, I get your point. Its Just that i dont like that cn1 loading spinner generated by InfiniteProgress , unless theres a ways to style it.

Comment: You can style anything in Codename One, how would you like it to look?

Comment: Maybe similar to the one i attached but without the Title. Just the rotating gif and  "Please wait text".

Comment: `Dialog dlg = new Dialog(new BorderLayout()); dlg.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new InfiniteProgress()); dlg.showModless();`